# UINavigationBar: add UILabel with moving effect

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I created UINavigationController application. I added UILabel to UINavigationBar, but there is a problem. My label is not moving when UINavigationBar is moving to left or to right. How do I solve the problem?

```
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0, 200, 44)] autorelease];
label.text = @"There are too car on the ...";
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you set the label directly on the UINavigationBar. If you don't need a customized label and the default behavior is enough for you, you should set the *UIViewController title* property instead. However, if you need a customized label, you should set your *UIViewController's navigationItem titleView* property. Check out the example below. I assume *self* is an active view controller:

```
// for a simple title, just set the view controllers title property
[self setTitle:@"There are too car on the ...";

// for a custom label, you need to set navigationItem.title property
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
label.text = @"There are too car on the ...";
label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:label];
```